# Disabling default tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a tooltip script, http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/simple-tooltip-with-jquery-only-text/. It works great in all the browsers but the default tooltip isn't disabled in IE.

How can i update the following script to disable the default tooltip?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Tooltip only Text
   $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
         // Hover over code
         var title = $(this).attr('title');
         $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
         $('<p class="tooltip"></p>').text(title).appendTo('body').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
         // Hover out code
         $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
         $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
          var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
          var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
          $('.tooltip').css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason to add the `title` attribute back in to the element on blur.  You have it stored in the jQuery metadata.  My guess is that is why IE is still showing it.  Remove the line

```
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
```

and see if that fixes it.

---

EDIT:  That missed some requirements.  This is untested, but might work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.masterTooltip').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
    }).hover(function(){
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .text($(this).data('tipText'))
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20;
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10;
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
    });
});
```

Note that this is sub-optimal, as it calls `$(this)` twice in the `each` block, but that should be easy enough to fix.

Comment: hi Scott, thanks for the instant reply.. i tried doing what you told me to.. now what is happening is, when i mouseover the image the first time, the default title and the tooltip both are appearing.. the second time, when i mouseover the same image, neither the title nor the tooltip is displayed..

Comment: Sorry, the lines that collect the title, and set the tipText also need to move out of the .hover branch and into an earlier .each section.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Glad it works.  There is definitely room for optimization, if you want.  There is no good reason to create and destroy the tooltip on every hover.  You could simply change text.  And you could also cache the call to `$(this)` in the `hover()` block.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution to disable the default tooltip which is shown in left/right bottom side of the IE or other browser. [If your default tooltip is same as I mentioned]

Just write a simple javascript function

```
function GoToLink()
    {
        location.href = "mypage.htm";
    }
```

call this function in tag like

```
<a id="204" name="wow" class="SettPage" href="" onclick="GoToLink()">
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. This does not disable the tooltip if you have a title attribute on an element.  This only prevents the target url from displaying in the status bar.