# Disable mouse over information for HTML elements

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

In both Chrome and Firefox when I move the mouse over the elements (ie. div, img, button) I get a small tool tip in the bottom right or left hand corner with something like `example.com/11.jpg`. I have already removed all the titles, so I know these aren't title related. What is this called and how do I get rid of this functionality?

[image: Strange tooltip]

Comment: I guess you should only get it when you mouseover a link. It shows the target URL of the link.

Comment: @bažmegakapa but how do I disable it. Is this client based? The "Add Comment" button to the right, for example, does not generate this "tooltip"

Comment: Because it is a button. As I tried to explain, only links (`<a href="">`) should trigger this tooltip. I think you should leave it to the user whether they like this feature or not - I find it very useful.

Comment: @bažmegakapa is there a serverside solution to disabling this? It is so ugly on a black background

Comment: It's a feature of the browser - even if there is a way to disable it, maybe you should not.

Comment: I think following will be helpful to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411851/disabling-default-tooltip/18887477#18887477

Comment: I think following will be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411851/disabling-default-tooltip/18887477#18887477

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltips will only appear when you hover over an `<a href="">` element. They show the URL the link points to.

As far as I know it cannot be turned off. For Firefox, there seems to be a [plugin (Status-4-Evar)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/) to restore the old functionality, but of course it is up to the user whether he wants to install it.

The following links seem to support what I say:

- [The pop up status bar. How do I turn the bloody thing off? - Google Groups](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/FtD7qjochgw%5B1-25%5D)
- [Entry in Firefox Bug Tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645313)
- [Turn off the link hover statusbar in Google Chrome - SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/239202/turn-off-the-link-hover-statusbar-in-google-chrome)

If there is no way for the user to disable this feature, I'm sure the website cannot disable it either.

Comment: In the old days, it was possible to prevent the display of status bar information on link mouseover by setting `window.status = ""`. There were reasons for removing this possibility; e.g., authors often deceptively showeda wrong URL or tried to hide the URL referred to.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It seems you can still spoof the URL the tooltip shows. But you can't hide it.

Comment: I don’t see how you could hide or change the status line display of the URL of a link. You can use a `title` attribute to create a tooltip, but that does not affect the status line.

Answer (score 1):

I **do not** recommend doing this, **but** you could change all your links (`<a href=""></a>`) to be rendered as other elements (i.e. `<span></span>`) an associate a url redirection behavior with jQuery.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6CrM/9/) shows a way you could do it.

Take into account that this will force the client to process all links in a page **every** time it is loaded, which brings some overhead on the loading. But if this is something you feel you must do then this would be one way to do it.

I would test it in all browsers to see how it performs, since I've had some issues in older versions of IE when deleting/replacing html elements, because of the implementation of that browser when manipulating the DOM.

Comment: That would be a terrible idea. Links affect too much things. I'd say it's not worth it, just for hiding those tooltips.

Comment: I completely agree, although I thought it was worth presenting some options.

Comment: I get it. But maybe you should list some of the downsides - there will be a lot.

Comment: You don’t *need* to use jQuery; it’s just a convenience. You could use event attributes in the markup directly. Either way, I don’t think efficiency is the issue; it’s more about usability. This kind of approach might be suitable for entirely JavaScript-driven applications, hardly for normal web sites.

Answer (score 1):

For firefox, enter url: about:config
Search for keyword: 'toolips'
Boolean Value = False
Voila! ... no more mouse-over url pop-ups

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely annoying to not be able to turn this off. As it turns out, Twitch has started making the entire video covered with links, so when you display a Twitch Live stream, the bottom portion of the screen is covered with this popup. There is no place on the screen to put the cursor where the bottom of the screen is not covered.

I would suggest that this is misuse of links by twitch, but never the less, having twitch do this calls for the browser to disable this feature so that we can see the bloody video.

Ok. the correct answer for Twitch misbehavior is browser.chrome.toolbar_tips false.

Thanks for listening.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! I would keep your answers to what is actually helping solve a question as this is not the place to write a blog. Thanks, I hope you understand!