# Insert url preview tags on an image

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to turn images into links without the `<a>` tag since the a tag messes up the spacing. However, I could not replicate the 'link preview' that shows at the bottom left of the screen when a link is hovered over

[image]

Is there any way I can make my `<img>` tags display a link preview like that when they are hovered over?

Answer (score 0):

Using Peter Rasmussen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30410812/2482123) from a similar question:

> Showing the link of an anchor tag is just how most browsers work.

Based on that, I believe browsers are using the anchor tags to use this "link preview" feature. A quick fix for this would be to keep your images inside `div` containers and then overlay the anchor tags above them.

```
<div>
    <a href="/somewhere"></a>
    <img>
</div>
```

However, as this can be considered bad practice, I would recommend taking the time to work **with** the browsers and not **against** them.

Edit: Additional information about it on another question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923025/2482123).